# How do I add and delete edges from a undirected graph represented with a adjacency list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, adjacency-list, undirected-graph

I need some help, I'm trying to create an adjacency list to represent a graph in C, I can add one edge to each node list, but I have no idea how to add more than one, I also dont know how to delete an edge , this is what I've got

edit 1 * I create the list inside the main function like an array:
 List *adjlist[Max]= {0};

```
typedef struct Node{
    int vertexNum;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct List{
    Node *head;
} List;

void Connect(List **adjlist, int v1, int v2){
    Node *dest, *tmp, *src;
    if(adjlist[v1]->head == NULL){
        src= (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        src->vertexNum = v2;
        src->next = NULL;
        adjlist[v1]->head=src;
    }

    dest = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    dest->vertexNum = v2;
    dest->next=NULL;
    tmp=adjlist[v1]->head;

    while(tmp->next != NULL){
        tmp= tmp->next;
    }

        adjlist = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Your list needs to hold "lists of nodes" instead of nodes.  Then each can hold more than 1 entry.  You could hard code an array of nodes to start with.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post the rest of your code. We need to see how this function is called and how the lists are initialized. Try to do as a _single_ code block, that is downloadable, compilable, and runnable. Provide enough sample input to demonstrate the problem. Do you have a single list of all neighbor relationships? If so, I'd say `List **adjlist` (vs. `List *adjlist`) is suspect.

Comment: `adjlist = tmp` doesn't seem to make much sense, given that `adjlist` is a `List**` and `tmp` is a `Node*`. Also, if the list is empty (i.e. head is `NULL`) you add the new `Node*` twice.